# Do we say "to lean the broom AGAINST / ON the corner of the room" or "to lean the broom IN the corner of the room"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

> **[lean](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lean_1?q=lean)** [transitive] to make something rest against something in a sloping position
>
> **lean something against something** Can I lean my bike against the
>   wall?
>
> She leaned her head against his shoulder.
>
> **lean something on something** He leaned his elbows on the table and
>   sighed.
>
> He sat down and leaned his chin on his right hand.

---

> **[corner](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/corner_1?q=corner)**: the place inside a room or a box where two sides join; the area around this place
>
> A large desk occupies another corner of the room.
>
> He found a quiet corner and got on with his work.
>
> **in the corner** They made straight for the table in the corner.
>
> **in the corner of something** She spotted him sitting in the corner
>   of the bar.
>
> We found an empty booth **in** a dark corner of the pub.
>
> There was a television **in** the far corner of the bedroom.
>
> a corner table/seat/cupboard

---

See this picture of a broom leaning AGAINST / ON / IN the corner.

[image]

Do we say "**to lean the broom AGAINST / ON the corner of the room**" or "**to lean the broom IN the corner of the room**"?

It is very hard to comprehend prepositions in English.

We normally use "**LEAN**" with "**AGAINST**" or "**ON**"

Eg, "**to lean the roll of mat AGAINST / ON the wall**"

But we often use "**CORNER**" with "**IN**"

Eg, "**There is a roll of mat IN the corner of the room**"

Comment: The verb is just lean, it’s not a phrasal verb. The proposition just follows the object: against the wall, in the corner

Comment: What do the numbers of Google hits for "broom in the corner" and "broom against the corner" seem to strongly indicate?

Comment: We need a picture of a corner?

Comment: If something was described as leaning _on_ or _against_ a corner I would expect the corner to be an _external_ corner. For example "As I walked down Joe's street he was leaning _on_ the corner of his house" as opposed to "As I entered the room Joe was leaning _in_ the corner by the window".

Comment: @YosefBaskin Well, it does include a broom ...

Comment: @BoldBen Are you sure he wasn't "leaning on the lamp-post, at the corner of the street, in case a certain little lady comes by..."